# subdomain redirect to subfolder using .htaccess and QNAP virtual host

Tags: redirect, subdomain, subdirectory, qnap

I have DNS managed by NO-IP and self hosted websites on a QNAP, with Virtual hosts defined in the Qnap Software.

My sites are `www.site1.com`, `www.site2.com` and a new `www.site3.com` which *(this one will work with subdomains created by wildcards at Users input in Joomla)* (ex `user1.site3.com` would be the redirection of the site3.com/index.php/users/user1) and all are located in (root) `web_folder/site1/...site2/...site3/` . The other sites have their virtual hosts working right.

Now, before doing that, i am getting stuck on this Qnap issue where i can't define my wildcard dns `*.site3.com` in the virtual hosts. I want to do this because when i enter in the browser anything.site3.com it gets me to the index.html file located in the root folder of my published sites (web/index.html)

What shoud I try in order for the subdomains to pass the root index and go directly to the website folder, where i could place my *.htaccess* containing the rewrite rules?

1. I tried with a .htaccess but couldn't manage what to write in order for it to work.
2. Define the wildcard in the qnap virtual host but does not accept

What am i thinking wrong?

[image]

I would like to avoid having a .htacces, in the web folder, to redirect every domain/subdomain to it's respective subfolder and afterwards having another .htaccess insinde my site3 folder which does the rest of the rewrites (subdomains wildcard and user based)

I have managed to do so far:

I shall partially answer to my question

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymlinks 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site3\.com<br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.site3\.com<br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.site3.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site3.com/index.php/user/%2 [L]
```

The thing is, I would like to still see `user.site3.com` instead of the full link.

Answer (score 0):

As an update. I am running wordpress multisite. My www.site3.com comes into the qnap(web or public_html folder) then the NAS virtual host manager redirects it to its actual subfolder (site3).
In this situation, when i write :

-**anything.site3.com** it reads my top (web or public_html) index and i can't get to the wordpress subpages. (my anything.site3.com page has been created from user-end)

-**site3.com** it goes to mi site3 folder as it should, managed by the qnap virtual host (i don't have to write additional htaccess.

So i need to somehow let my subdomains pass the redirection from the qnap and go to my site3 subfolder and then wordpress htaccess do it's job. **This should be done so that i don't have a continuous loop**!

Sorry for my explanations might be a little bit messed.

Comment: This is an answer or part of the question? (It sounds like an answer ...)